# Can I use JavaScript JSON.parse with an external array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I need to get data from an external file; I tried to make an ajax request, but I only seem to get all the data as a string. I'm having trouble using JSON.parse; I get **'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'xmlhttp.onreadystatechange'**. I know it may be because I'm not getting JSON data. This is what I have so far:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var jn = JSON.parse(data);
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = jn;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "Users.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
```

This is what I get from "Users.php" as a string, but not as an array:

```
[['@user1',238,'img/user1.jpeg'],['@user2',220,'img/user2.jpeg'],['@user3',180,'img/user1.jpeg']]
```

How do I retrieve all the data from the string, or turn it to an array? I even tried using the split function, but I couldn't get it right.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why the `jquery` tag?

Comment: You cannot return valid JSON instead? you could try eval() but it REALLY is not a great practice here, it will return an array of arrays.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

May be it is a bit of a work but is it possible for you to escape the quotes within the string ? Then it would be able to parse.

Example: send the following response from your PHP :

```
[[\"@user1\",238,\"img/user1.jpeg\"],[\"@user2\",220,\"img/user2.jpeg\"]]
```

Then it should be able to parse using JSON.parse()

Just make sure you do not have line breaks in your response.

Comment: why not create a standard PHP array with all your vars and use `json_encode()` as @Andreas suggested. It would be far better that what this answer suggests. It would be correctly formatted and there would be no need for escaping double quotes, like this!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If you're in control of Users.php then you can solve the issue by using json_encode() on your data. That will make use of double quotes to wrap strings and result in exactly what I suggested below without the replace()

**Previously**

json expects strings to be surrounded by double, not single quotes.

So a hack would be `JSON.parse(data.replace("'", '"'))`

You could of course trip over if there are any double quotes or escaped single quotes in the returned string.